# Group action generated by two homeomorphism and group action $\varphi:\langle a, b\rangle\times X\to X$

Tags: dynamical-systems, group-actions

Let $F_2=\langle a, b \rangle$ be a free group and let $f, g:X\to X$ be two homeomorphism on compact metric space with $f\circ g\neq id_X$.

Assume that $\varphi:F_2\times X\to X$ is defined by $\varphi(a, x)= f(x)$ and $\varphi(b, x)= g(x)$. Hence, if $t=a^n b^m$, then $\varphi(t, x)= f^n(g^m(x))$, where $f^n(x)= f\circ\ldots \circ f(x)$, $n$-times.

Also, denote by $\psi$ group action generated by $f, g$.

What is different between $\varphi$ and $\psi$?

Can I defined $\psi$ as a group action of $F_2\times X\to X$?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, If $G$ is the group action generated by $f, g:X\to X$, then for $g\in G$, there exist $n, m\in \mathbb{Z}$ with $g=f^n\circ g^m$, i.e. $\{f^n\circ g^m:m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ and composition between two function as operation. Take $\psi(g, x)= g(x)$.